# jquery requires click to twice on selected tab

Tags: jquery, css, click

i'm having a little problem with jquery and counting on your help.
I have a custom sortable tabs, but, when I click on selected item, I have to click twice, to change the order.

here's a demo of script: http://jsfiddle.net/7e3UV/1/

try to click on .active class button, on first link for example, you'll see that it requires click to second time for change it's arrow ...

so, can anyone help me, understand why this is doing like that?

HTML:

```
<div id="sort">
    <a href="#" data-sort="views" data-order="desc" class="active">views <span>&darr;</span></a>
    <a href="#" data-sort="rating" data-order="desc">rating <span>&darr;</span></a>
    <a href="#" data-sort="date" data-order="desc">date <span>&darr;</span></a>                         
</div><!-- #sort -->
```

JS:

```
var body = $('body');

body.on('click', 'div#sort > a', function(e){

    var self = $(this);

    // if clicked on active tab
    if( self.hasClass('active') )
    {
        console.log('active');

        if( self.data('order') === 'asc' )
        {                    
            console.log('active asc');
            self.data('order', 'desc');
            self.children('span').html('&uarr;');
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('active desc');    
            self.data('order', 'asc');
            self.children('span').html('&darr;');
        }

    }

    // add and remove .active class
    self.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: If you're able to provide a self-contained code sample on jsFiddle, you should also provide one here. Always imagine your question could be solved based on what's in your question alone, without external resources. I've gone ahead and copied them over here for you. ;-)

Comment: Thanks, for doing that, I'll consider that.

Answer (score 4):

You need to swap your `&darr;` and `&uarr;`.  You have a down arrow for descending in html, but then a down arrow for ascending in code, with a up arrow for descending.

Comment: Just made the same discovery. Legit.

Answer (score 0):

The first click makes the link active.
As soon as a link is active every additional click changes the sort direction.

That is the reason why you have to click twice.
First click to activate, second one for changing sort order.

Comment: But in order to get the arrow to change, you actually have to click a previously inactive link 3 times. First to set it active, second to change the order but set the arrow incorrectly, and third to change the order and the arrow.

Comment: Yes, but that is only because (how you already said) the initial arrows in his html are the wrong ones. but the script functions as I said and his question was to explain him, why he has to click twice to change the direction.